# How do I blit pixel data to the screen using OpenGL ES?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, pixel

I'm currently learning OpenGL ES for iPhone and I'm wondering how to take an array of RGB pixel data and blit it to the screen, so far all the tutorials I've found cover loading a pre-existing image into a texture and displaying it.

Here's how I've accomplished it using Core Graphics by creating an imageref then using a UIImage and UIImageView:

```
int screenWidth = (int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
int screenHeight = (int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

//Create blank image
CGImageRef blankImageRef = [self createBlankImageRef];
CFDataRef m_DataRef; 
m_DataRef = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(blankImageRef)); 
UInt8* bufferData = CFDataGetBytePtr(m_DataRef); 


//Manipulate the image here
for(int x=0; x < screenWidth-1; x++)
{
    int y = x;//*2;

    [self setPixel:bufferData width:screenWidth x:x y:y r:255 g:0 b:0];
}


//Paint the image to the screen
CGImageRef imageRef = blankImageRef; 
CGContextRef ctx; 
ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(bufferData, 
                            CGImageGetWidth( imageRef ), 
                            CGImageGetHeight( imageRef ), 
                            8, 
                            CGImageGetBytesPerRow( imageRef ), 
                            CGImageGetColorSpace( imageRef ), 
                            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast ); 
screenImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx)]; 
CGContextRelease(ctx); 

[imageView setImage:screenImage];

free(bufferData);
```

...

```
- (CGImageRef) createBlankImageRef
{
CGFloat imageScale = (CGFloat)1.0;
CGFloat width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
CGFloat height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

// Create a bitmap graphics context of the given size
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width * imageScale, height * imageScale, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

// Draw ...
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, (CGFloat)0.0, (CGFloat)0.0, (CGFloat)0.0, (CGFloat)1.0 );

// Get your image
CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);

return cgImage;
}

-(void)setPixel:(UInt8*)buffer width:(int)width x:(int)x y:(int)y r:(int)r g:(int)g b:(int)b
{
buffer[x*4 + y*(width*4)] = r;
buffer[x*4 + y*(width*4)+1] = g;
buffer[x*4 + y*(width*4)+2] = b;
buffer[x*4 + y*(width*4)+3] = 255;
}
```

Any ideas how I could accomplish this using OpenGL ES (currently using 1.0) instead of Core Graphics?

Comment: Create a full-screen quad, and write a small shader that takes your pixel data as a Texture2D and fill it in with no lighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a texture by using `glTexImage2D` (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) or `glTexSubImage2D` (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml). `glTexSubImage2D` is mainly for updating textures in real time.

e.g. for an RGBA texture:

```
GLubyte texBuffer[4*texWidth*texHeight];
GLuint texName;
glGenTextures(1, &texName) ;
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName) ;
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texBuffer);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

if you're using ES 1.x you can also use `glDrawPixels` (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml).

Comment: Could the texBuffer be in GLuint format or must it be Glubyte?

Comment: well, you could declare texBuffer as `GLuint texBuffer[texWidth*texHeight]` - the key thing is that the size is equal to `sizeof(GLubyte) * 4 * texWidth * texHeight`. (4 in this case assuming you want 4 components - ie. RGBA). the difference will come when you fill the texBuffer before calling `glTexImage2D` (you'll need to pack the 4 components into one uint before setting that pixel in the buffer). note that you'd keep the glTexImage2D call the same.